# HTTPS Request with Perl UserAgent

Tags: perl, https, lwp, charles-proxy

I am trying to request an html document with HTTPS authentication using Perl.  I haven't had an issue with non-HTTPS code in the past.  I'm currently using LWP::UserAgent:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use LWP;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $baseurl = "https://xyz.url.com/directory";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->cookie_jar({});
$ua->credentials('xyz.url.com:80', '', 'login', 'password');

my $response = $ua->get($baseurl);
print  $response->content();
```

The response that is printed is essentially the '401 Unauthorized' page.  I am able to login via the browser.  The browser uses a pop-up that reads 'Authentication Required -- The server xyz.url.com:80 requires a username and password.  The server says: Blah Blah'  I have read many posts instructing to install things like `Crypt::SSLeay` and `LWP::Protocol::https`.  These are installed.  I'm stumped.

I've also downloaded a program called Charles to see if there is anything of note with the request/response, however I'm not really sure where to look.  I've tried adding 'Blah Blah' for the realm, but this wasn't successful.  Can the realm be identified using Charles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't my LWP::UserAgent credentials work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799147/why-dont-my-lwpuseragent-credentials-work)

Comment: That question is similar, and one that I read prior to posting this one.  However, I don't have a solution, and I'd appreciate if someone walked me through using Charles or some other tool to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that the first argument to credentials is `<host>:<port>` — that is, the port number isn't optional. Try `"xyz.url.com:443"`. Also, a realm of `''` isn't going to be valid unless that's what the server is sending; you actually want to use `"Blah Blah"` for the realm, I believe.

Comment: I've tried adding the port and the realm, however I'm not confident that the realm I've specified is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because you have not set a proper agent.  Try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use LWP;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $baseurl = "https://xyz.url.com/directory";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0');
$ua->cookie_jar({});
$ua->credentials('xyz.url.com', '', 'login', 'password');

my $response = $ua->get($baseurl);
print  $response->content();
```

Also, I removed the variable `$browser` in my code as it appears you were not using it for anything.