# Authentication credentials were not provided issue

Tags: perl, web-services, credentials, restful-url, lwp-useragent

I have a problem in send Restful request to HotelsPro web service.

Iam trying to send request to this link https://api-test.hotelspro.com:443 with basic credentials but I get error every time "Authentication credentials were not provided" although this credentials is working on browser.My code like follow

```
 sub getJSONdata {

    my ($SupplierXMLServer, $message, $compressed,$timeOut) = ();
       ($SupplierXMLServer, $message, $compressed,$timeOut) = @_;

    $SupplierXMLServer='https://api-test.hotelspro.com/api/v2/search/?destination_code=20b05&checkin=2016-11-09&checkout=2016-11-12&currency=USD&client_nationality=PS&pax=2';

    my $username = "Epilgrim";
    my $password = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    use LWP::UserAgent;
    my $userAgent = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent =>"1");
       $userAgent->credentials('https://api-test.hotelspro.com:443', 'api', $username , $password);
       $userAgent->timeout($timeOut) if($timeOut);  # in seconds
    use HTTP::Request::Common;
    my $response = '';
    if($compressed){
         $response = $userAgent->request( GET $SupplierXMLServer,
                                          Content_Type => 'application/json',
                                          Accept_Encoding => "gzip,deflate",
                                          Content => $message);
    }
    else{
         $response = $userAgent->request( GET $SupplierXMLServer,
                                          Content_Type => 'application/json',
                                          Content => $message);
    }
    return $response->error_as_HTML unless $response->is_success;
      #return $response->content;

    if($compressed){
    return $response->decoded_content;
  }

    else{
        return $response->content;
      }
    }
```

Please help me to write the correct code and send the request in correct way to get valid response.

Comment: In your call to `credentials`, can you try removing the protocol - it should be of the format `hostname:port` - i.e. `'api-test.hotelspro.com:443'`

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799147/why-dont-my-lwpuseragent-credentials-work

Answer (score 1):

The given link redirects to https://api-test.hotelspro.com/login/?next=/, which is looking a Form Based Authentication page. But in your Perl script, you are trying Basic Authentication. Please check google to understand the difference between [Basic Auth vs Form Based Auth](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=basic%20authentication%20vs%20form%20authentication).

Now, in order to perform Form Based Auth, its better to use WWW::Mechanize which is a wrapper around LWP but provide more convenient methods. Following is a sample code for Form Based Auth right from [WWW::Mechanize's official help page:](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Examples.pod)

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w -T

use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $login    = "login_name";
my $password = "password";
my $folder   = "folder";

my $url = "http://img78.photobucket.com/albums/v281/$login/$folder/";

# login to your photobucket.com account
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields      => { password => $password },
);
die unless ($mech->success);

# upload image files specified on command line
foreach (@ARGV) {
    print "$_\n";
    $mech->form_number(2);
    $mech->field('the_file[]' => $_);
    $mech->submit();
}
```

Hope this helps!